# Gray-Scott simulation does not expand symmetrically

Tags: python, simulation

I wrote a Gray-Scott simulation that is designed to create Turing patterns however the pattern it creates does not expand symmetrically and uses different kill and feed rates to work. It still generates the patterns but there is a randomness to them which I cannot find the reason for.

```
def Laplace(loc0,loc1,loc2,loc3,loc4,loc5,loc6,loc7,loc8):
    lap = ((loc0*0.05) + (loc1*0.2) + (loc2*0.05) + (loc3*0.2) + (loc4*-1) + (loc5*0.2) + (loc6*0.05) + (loc7*0.2) + (loc8*0.05))
    return lap

for reps in range(epochs):
    for i in range(height-1):
        for j in range(width-1):
            
            aChem = aConc[i, j] + (aDiffRate * (Laplace(aConc[i-1,j-1],aConc[i-1,j],aConc[i-1,j+1],aConc[i,j-1],aConc[i,j],aConc[i,j+1],aConc[i+1,j-1],aConc[i+1,j],aConc[i+1,j+1])) - aConc[i, j]* (bConc[i,j]**2)) + feedRate * (1 - aConc[i, j]) * dT
            bChem = bConc[i,j] + (bDiffRate * (Laplace(bConc[i-1,j-1],bConc[i-1,j],bConc[i-1,j+1],bConc[i,j-1],bConc[i,j],bConc[i,j+1],bConc[i+1,j-1],bConc[i+1,j],bConc[i+1,j+1])) + aConc[i, j]* (bConc[i,j]*2)) - (killRate + feedRate)* bConc[i,j] * dT

            aConc[i, j] = max(0, min(1, aChem))
            bConc[i, j] = max(0, min(1, bChem))
```

I originally thought it was to my Laplace being wrong but I checked and it seems fine and I checked the rounding and it doesn't seem to be responsible either and it wouldn't make sense either as the pattern always favours expanding in the bottom right. Below is the code for the Laplace and my working feed and kill rates are when both are 0.192 if that helps.

https://www.karlsims.com/rdtool.html?s=0PPIjNw

In the simulation above you will see when it starts from the centre the symmetrical expansion. The image attached shows the expansion of mine[Asymmetrically expanding Turing patten](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwoar.png)

Comment: Is `aConc[i-1,j-1]` supposed to be the updated value (you’re updating in place) or the previous value? Also, what does that do at `i == 0`/`j == 0`?

Comment: @Ry-  'aConc[i-1,j-1]' is the value of cell up 1 and to the left of the current cell and I don't know what happens when they're 0 nothing changes when I start from 1 so its not a boundary condition thing.

Comment: What I’m saying is that `aConc[i-1,j-1]` (and the left/upper neighbors) will have already been updated by an earlier iteration of your loop by the time you read it.